# Setting USB Sound Card to default device

Tags: raspbian, audio, alsa

I have been using raspberry pi 3 model B. And,
I have installed raspbian jessie with pixel.

I made work its camera without an error. I have bought USB sound Card. But, I couldn't make it to work. My `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file

```
options snd-usb-audio index=0
options snd_bcm2835 index=1
options snd slots=snd-usb-audio,snd-bcm2835
```

It is insisting to use HDMI audio output. raspi-conf didn't help me. Also I can hear with

```
aplay -D plughw:0,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

My `aplay -l` output

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 1: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and I have edited /etc/asound.conf file as this

> npcm.!default {
>
> ```
> type hw
>
> card 0
> ```
>
> } ctl.!default{
>
> ```
> type hw
>
> card 0
> ```
>
> }

But nothing changed. It is forcing to use HDMI audio output. How can I configure alsa to usb sound card as default.

Comment: What is "it"? If you are referring to PulseAudio, it has its own configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I fixed my issue with installing padevchooser and made necessary configuration with it. But I have to run pulseaudio after every boot.

Comment: isn't your asound.conf file meant to list "pcm.!default" rather then "npcm.!default" ?

Comment: Please see [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/80072/how-can-i-use-an-external-usb-sound-card-and-set-it-as-default) for full solution and details.